# problemas para acceder a API curl con JS

Tags: javascript, api, curl, async

Un proveedor tiene una API que sería la siguiente

```
$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxxx:yyyyyyy");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xxxx.yyyy.com/api/clientes");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
  $retorno = curl_exec($ch);
  $error = curl_errno($ch);
  if ($error) {
    echo "Error; " . $error;
  } else {
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retorno;
  }
```

la cosa está en que no consigo acceder a los datos, y el proveedor no da soporte para JS, tan solo da soporte para PHP, en php me funciona bien, pero lo que quiero es acceder diréctamente a través del front a los datos y simplemente mostrarlos.

Adjunto el código que estoy ejecutando:

```
(async () => {
    fetch("https://xxxx.dominio.com/api/clientes/1", {
        mode: "cors",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic xxxxxx:yyyyyyyy",
        },
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json));
})();
```

---

el código lo ejecuto desde el cliente, en mi navegador. Y tengo el plugin CORS habilitado y añado el mode: "cors" al header.

de hecho con la aplicación PAW for mac, creo la conexión y me da ok, me muestra los registros pero si lo ejecuto desde el js en el navegador me falla.
adjunto el Fetch JS exportado, si lo probais no funcionara porque esta limitada a ip.

```
// Request (GET https://citra.ispgestion.com/api/clientes/251)
fetch("https://citra.ispgestion.com/api/clientes/251", {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Basic bnJlZGVzOjVFbnViZUAyMDE4",
            "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=47977hfeq3lcvdrkshrpdrteea"
      }
})
.then((res) => res.text())
.then(console.log.bind(console))
.catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: ¿El código JS lo estas ejecutando del lado del cliente (_eg: navegador_)? Por que podría ser un problema de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Cuando dices "problema al acceder"... que error sale? que muestra la consola? cual es el codigo HTTP de la respuesta?

Comment: si hago todo el código en PHP me funciona bien, pero si lo hago en JS constantemente me da errores, he creado la conexión con PAW for mac, y lo he exportado a Fetch JS, pero me da estos datos, y la autenticación no es la misma.
```
fetch("https://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/api/clientes/1", {
 method: "GET",
 headers: {
  mode: "no-core",
  Authorization: "Basic bnJlZGVzOsdfsjVFbnViZUAyMDE4",
  Cookie: "PHPSESSID=47977hfeq3lcvdrkshrpdrteea",
 },
})
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

el proveedor tiene capado el acceso JS por navegador. Peticiones por cliente y no por servidor.

gracias

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o un comentario a la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Porque no consumes un archivo **PHP** que ejecute el **curl** y devuelves los datos en formato **json** o similar a tu Frontend de esa manera no deberías tener problemas, es más fácil y viable hacerlo así.

En vez de hacer el **fetch** a ellos lo haces a ese archivo **PHP**.

Espero mi respuesta te ayude.

Comment: eso es lo que tengo ahora, pero creo que no tengo necesidad de crear archivos php para alimentar el JS, si puedo alimentarlos directamente al JS, no'

Comment: @NOEMORENO Eso que dices es una mala práctica, en el front debe haber la menor lógica posible. Las APIs se consumen desde el backend en tu caso PHP. Entonces lo que deberías hacer es recibir dicha llamada en PHP, y estos datos mostrarlos en tu frontend en Javascript

Comment: @NOEMORENO tal como lo dice RoyalUp, las API por lo general se consumen desde PHP excepto estés trabajando en una aplicación móvil o similar y la api te permita con javascript consumirla, en tu caso lo mejor es la recomendación que te di.

Comment: @Spearking, quizás no me he expresado bien, la API del proveedor ya me da los datos en JSON, por eso digo que no le encuentro lógica a crear otra API u otros archivos para volver a retornar los datos, que son los mismos.

Comment: @RoyalUp  quizás no me he expresado bien, la API del proveedor ya me da los datos en JSON, por eso digo que no le encuentro lógica a crear otra API u otros archivos para volver a retornar los datos, que son los mismos.

Comment: Si te los da pero no te permite consumir dicha api desde javascript, por lo que hagas lo que hagas no podrás consumirla desde javascript, por eso está recomendación.